# Lightning design system how to find scoping class of static resource

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system, slds

So... going through the trailheads, last month, I've already created the static resource of the SLDS.  However in a new trailhead I'm back to the design system.  In this I'm required to update the 'scoping class' name in the VF page.  However I don't remember what that was.

My question: How do I find the scoping name that was created for the static resource which was loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to download the static resource, changed its file extension to .zip, unzip it and then open the file:

```
assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css
```

You will see your namespace all over the place (`cv-slds` in this example):

```
.cv-slds {
  /*! normalize.css v3.0.2 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */
  /*! HTML5 Boilerplate v5.2.0 | MIT License | https://html5boilerplate.com/ */ }
  .cv-slds {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    margin: 0; }
    .cv-slds article,
    .cv-slds aside,
    .cv-slds details,
    .cv-slds figcaption,
    .cv-slds figure,
    .cv-slds footer,
    .cv-slds header,
    .cv-slds hgroup,
    .cv-slds main,
    .cv-slds menu,
    ...
```

Or you could use your browser's Development Tools to do the same thing.